# Nexus 7 for Android development with Eclipse

Tags: android, nexus-7

I would first start off with saying sorry If I tagged this in the wrong section. However, I consider this a development question. I'm thinking on getting the Nexus 7 tablet (running Jellybean).
However, Is this tablet any good to develope on? considering the screen size is not HUGE, neither small.
And is there any difference developing on Jellybean?
As I couldn't find any opinions on this anywhere I decided to ask here.

Again, sorry If I'm tagging the wrong things. Feel free to edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the nexus 7 is a good enough tablet platform for developement. I have tried a few things i made there myself.

Comment: Is the size good for an overview of the app you create? or would you say it is to similar to Samsung Galaxy S2 (currently using that). @kabuto178

Comment: As for the size. It really depends on your applications target audience. Try resizing the screen size on your eclipse when creating layouts. Personal opinion on the device. Should be great on development because it will always be update regarding the os.

Comment: it is good for an overall development :D, you can change layout sample sizes in eclipse to get an idea of positioning then see it live on the nexus 7

Comment: Sounds about good enough for me to buy it. Especially considering the price range it has. Thank you fellow developers! @IrishFringe

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the screen size and the dpi of the device.

For Nexus 7, it is large screen and tvdpi which is not suitable for mobile apps.

Mostly, mobile device has normal screen with hdpi.

Comment: I have a mobile device, but I need a tablet to show some of my apps on a tablet format aswell.... so that I why I was thinking Nexus 7 as it is still transferable in a pocket etc.

Answer (score 0):

i think one difference at least in older tablets is that theres one less route for the audio (mic)